Why does this Wix site go to a blank page when refreshed, or when accessed directly using the URL?
Question:
https://www.roofaesthetics.com/book
Does anyone know why this page is blank when you go directly to that URL? But when you access that page by clicking on the menu link (like from the home page), it loads fine. But when you refresh that page, it goes blank.
If it is related to having javascript errors, then could you please help me figure out how to change that? I am not good at javascript (sorry).
Product:
Wix Editor
What are you trying to achieve:
I would like the page to load properly, not go blank.
Additional information:
This is for a client’s site. I am not very good at coding, so please bear with me. I appreciate your patience with me.
What have you already tried:
Searched Google and Wix Studio Forum
I've posted on reddit. I was told that the page has lots of javascript errors.
I've deleted the page and made a new page called /book2, which works fine. However, the client wants it to be /book. Even when I duplicate /book2 and call it /book (after deleting the original /book page), the problem comes back.
The page works fine when I change the slug to anything but /book.
I deleted any redirects on the redirect manager.

check if "book" is a route which is used in a conflicting way (like with Wix bookings module) or points to a non-existing class/page

I'm so sorry to ask this beginner question, but how do I check that? Would I be looking at the code? What am I looking for in the code? Or if you could send me a link to read to figure out how to do this, that would be great. Sorry, I think I am in a little over my head. Thank you for your help.

do you have that module installed? https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-bookings-about-wix-bookings: in case you have, "book" has become a reserved route

When I go to apps and search for that module, it is not installed (it gives me the "Add to site" option). So I think it is not installed. I looked at the inspector -> console and see these errors (I think they are errors?):

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED https://jelly-v6.mdhv.io/v1/starV6.gif?evt=hi&pid=j9yAAVNfJ3E6KW2lY4OjvEWDh9eI&src=mh&tx=f797bf7d-b083-42a9-ba9a-b4746e40343f
react-i18next:: It seems you are still using the old wait option, you may migrate to the new useSuspense behaviour.
utils.js:11

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED https://jelly-v6.mdhv.io/v1/starV6.gif?evt=hi&pid=j9yAAVNfJ3E6KW2lY4OjvEWDh9eI&src=mh&tx=bb01aded-7219-4dbc-a629-fdb2f461cf36

The resource https://siteassets.parastorage.com/pages/pages/thunderbolt?appDefinitionId... was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally.
This error is listed twice. I assume the URLs, which are very long and too long to put here, are different.

The apps installed on the client's site: Wix FAQ, Wix Members Area, Google Reviews PRO, Wix Forms, Wix Pro Gallery, Wix Forms & Payments

Actually, the error "The resource siteassets.parastorage.com/pages/pages/…... was preloaded..." is listed 6 times.

Is it https://www.roofaesthetics.com/booking you were looking for?

No, it's /book. /book redirects to /booking, which is a workaround that the client is okay with now, but the client originally wanted /book. /book is the page that's causing the problem.

if the /book page isn’t loading properly, javascript errors or caching issues could be the problem, especially if similar pages like /book2 work fine. to troubleshoot, first check for javascript errors using the browser’s developer console, comparing the /book page to /book2 to spot any issues. clear both your browser and wix cache, as cached versions can sometimes store old or broken content. if /book has been previously used, it may have leftover redirects or settings causing conflicts. check wix’s redirect manager to ensure no hidden redirects are interfering, as these can automatically generate with page renames or deletions. if acceptable, consider permanently assigning /book2 to the existing page and setting a redirect from /book. alternatively, create a clean test page using the /book slug; if this loads correctly, gradually add elements to find any annoying code.

I have deleted everything from that page except for header and footer, and it's still happening. The only sections on the page are 1) the one containing the form and 2) the one containing a banner image (it's right below the header, above the section with the form). I deleted both, and the problem remains.
One thing I noticed is that on refresh or when the URL is accessed directly, the title tag (the words in the browser tab) goes from "Book A Free Inspection" (correct) to "Home" (incorrect), while the URL stays as /book.
Do you have any thoughts on what that might mean?
